# Share Dialog not working from react native fb sdk (undefined)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I copied the example exactly from the facebook example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/sharing .

The problem is that when I hit the function i get undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ShareDialog.canShow' . I know it is referring to the ShareDialog object.

I am importing it using the line

```
import {ShareDialog} from 'react-native-fbsdk';
```

The code for my function is:

```
shareOnFacebook () {
        var tmp = this;
        ShareDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
            function(canShow) {
                if (canShow) {
                    return ShareDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
                }
            }
        ).then(
            function(result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    alert('Share cancelled');
                } else {
                    alert('Share success with postId: ' + result.postId);
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Share fail with error: ' + error);
            }
        );

    }
```

Comment: Did you install the Facebook SDK on your native platform? Which platform are you using, iOS or Android?

Comment: @Devesh, did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same problem even though my imports are resolving in objective-c

Comment: @Tyler The problem is my case was that I was using Expo to create my react-native app and to use the 'react-native-fbsdk' I had to link the project, which was not possible unless I ejected. In your case if you are not using expo then you need to install the library and make sure to link it to your project.